# Data Warehouse example - simply explained

Tags: data-warehouse

I'm trying to learn about Data Warehouses right now, but I really don't get it. My question isn't really specific, but I just want somebody to explain to me the idea of data warehouses.

I'm trying right now to create a data warehouse out of [SO's database](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange).

In this database there are 8 tables, they are pretty self-explanatory for those who use SO:

- Badges
- Comments
- PostHistory
- PostLinks
- Posts
- Tags
- Users
- Votes

**1. Dimensions**
What would be the dimensions? That's the big part I don't understand. For me I see 7 dimensions: Badges, Comments, Posts, PostLinks, Tags, Users and Votes. But then I don't see the point of using data warehouses, the dimensions are exactly the tables.

-Would date be a dimension? Date of what? Of each comment AND post?
-Would it be relevant to separate Post into a Question dimension and an Answer dimension?
-What other dimensions can I put?

**2. Fact Table**
How can I put all the foreign keys (userId, postId, commentId...) in one table? For example, let's say a user posts a question but there's no comment. I would have a line in my fact table with his userId, the postId an NULL in the commentId column?

Measures. I'm thinking of the following measures in the fact table: number of questions, number of users, number of tags...

Can someone tell me about if I'm going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The first question you have to answer when building a data warehouse is "What question(s) do I want to answer?"

Using Stack Overflow as an example, one question could be, "How many posts are there about X each month over the last 2 years?"

To answer this question, we need to create Posts and Post Tags fact tables.  Since these tables are select and insert only, we can denormalize the fact data so it's easier to select.

So, we might have a Post fact table that looks something like this.

```
Post
----
Post Number
Post Text
Post Timestamp
Post Tag 1
Post Tag 2
Post Tag 3
Post Tag 4
Post Tag 5
```

It would be somewhat straightforward to select based on the timestamp and group by month.  We only care about the first 5 post tags, and we don't care if some of them are null.

Now, you don't have to denormalize the data.  Generally, queries run faster if you denormalize the data.

You do the same thing for the other data available.  What question(s) do you want to answer?

Comment: Some questions I would ask are: "What are the most popular tags?" or "Which are the most active users (in terms of posts and comments)?" But then, why would I need a data warehouse for that?

Comment: @amaurymartiny: Most companies don't keep as much historical data in their operational data base as Stack Overflow does.  Yes, you can answer your Stack Overflow questions with the operational data base.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is probably not the best data model to consider if you're trying to wrap your head around the concept of DW.  It doesn't contain many "traditional" facts.  The only examples which jump to my mind immediately are the Up/Down votes and the user rankings.

You would find many, of what we call "factless facts".  These essentially treat the intersection of multiple dimensions as a fact, with just an implied "count" as the sole fact.  As an example, in the Post Fact, it would simply be a count at the intersection of User, Date, SO Database, etc.

You would probably consider a concept such as the Junk dimension to support referencing the Tags in a Fact table.  This would see you assign a pseudo key to each unique combination of Tags, and then this key is what you would store in the Fact table.

If you want to learn about DW, use your personal finances, this is how I learned.  You can learn about snapshot facts with your account balances, you can learn about transactional facts with your purchases, and you can create Vendor and Account dimensions, among others.